# Android - Error Uploadin file to FTP

Tags: android, csv, android-asynctask, ftp

I'm trying to upload to FTP two types of files: a CSV and one or more jpg. The problem is that the csv uploads correctly but the jpg gives me error "Java.Lang.InterruptedExeption" . 
Anyone know what the problem is?

```
class UploaderFoto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String miFoto = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            String dirNombre = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Formulario/";
            FileInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(dirNombre + "temp.csv");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                ftpClient.connect("ip");

                if (!ftpClient.login("user", "pass")) {
                    cancel(true);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("Cancelado", "No se pudo conectar con el servidor");

                } else {

                    if (ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("NubeGIS")) {
                        Log.d("Cambiado", "Se cambio a la carpeta NubeGIS");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Error", "No Se cambio a la carpeta NubeGIS");
                    }
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    if (ftpClient.storeFile("temp.csv", in)) {
                        Log.d("Ok", "Se subio el formulario");
                        in.close();
                    } else {
                        cancel(true);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("Cancelado", "Ya existe el archivo");
                    }

                    StringBuilder listadoCompleto = cargarListado();

                    if (listadoCompleto.length() > 0) {

                        String[] lines = listadoCompleto.toString().split("__");

                        int cont = 1;
                        for (String s : lines) {
                            Log.d("Leyendo", "archivo " + cont);

                            BufferedInputStream ini = null;
                            ini = new BufferedInputStream(
                                    new FileInputStream(dirNombre + s));


                            if (ftpClient.storeFile(s, ini)) {
                                Log.d("OK", "Se subio la imagen " + cont);
                                cont++;
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Error", "Error al subir la imagen");
                                cancel(true);
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
                        Log.d("Termindo", "archivo " + cont);

                    }

                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LOGTAG", "Error", e);
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Subiendo el archivo, espere.");
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Archivo subido",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            File fichero = new File("storage/sdcard0/Formulario/temp.csv");
            fichero.delete();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No se pudo conectar al servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

LOGCAT

```
09-29 10:32:11.918: D/Cambiado(10510): Se cambio a la carpeta NubeGIS
09-29 10:32:11.948: D/Leyendo(10510): archivo 1
09-29 10:32:12.018: D/Error(10510): Error al subir la imagen
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510): java.lang.InterruptedException
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1280)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:219)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:295)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:293)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:75)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:467)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at com.example.formularioandroid.MainActivity$UploaderFoto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1376)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at com.example.formularioandroid.MainActivity$UploaderFoto.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-29 10:32:12.048: W/AsyncTask(10510):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-29 10:32:12.048: D/Termindo(10510): archivo 1
```

Comment: can you post the logcat error?

Comment: i guess the problem is `ini = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dirNombre + s));`, are you sure its correct?

Comment: The problem was the variable s there was a ":" character that caused the error. Thanks for help